# Traveling to India (home country) from UK on Tier 2

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, indian-citizens

I am in UK on Tier 2 General visa and I have,

- 7 weeks of annual holidays
- Additional 4 weeks unpaid parental holidays approved by employer

Can I take these holidays to go to India ?

reading 26.19 from here
https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/492799/Tier_25_guidance_11-15_word_v1_1_addendum.pdf

```
26.19 The only other exceptions to this rule are:
a) where the reduction is due to the migrant taking a period of:
 maternity leave
 paternity leave
 shared parental leave
 adoption leave
 long-term sick leave in excess of one continuous calendar month
```

Does this include this,

https://www.gov.uk/parental-leave/overview

Comment: What are 'unpaid parental holidays'? Is this something specifically defined by your employer in their general employee rules? Is this is special arrangement just for you? Is it defined in your employment contract? Why would you be taking these days? If you can answer these questions, we can probably answer yours.

Comment: @ouflak I already added link to unpaid parental holidays in my question, please see the last link in the question, this has nothing to do with my employer but with UK government's immigration rules, I think you need to read my question once again :)

Comment: "...this has nothing to do with my employer ..." You have to be eligible.

Comment: Just to clarify, as it was a bit confusing, you referred to the Unpaid Parental Leave and Unpaid parental holidays. This is not correct. They *might* in fact be holidays, but this leave may be for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @ouflak as stated before, please read my question properly, I already said that Unpaid parental Leave (holidays) are approved by employers which means I am eligible, why are you not reading my question properly before commenting ?

Answer (score 2):

From the link on [Shared Parental Leave.](https://www.gov.uk/shared-parental-leave-and-pay/overview) A quote:

> You may be able to get Shared Parental Leave (SPL) and Statutory Shared > Parental Pay (ShPP) if:
>
> your baby is due on or after 5 April 2015
>
> you adopt a child on or after 5 April 2015
>
> If you’re eligible for SPL you can use it to take leave in blocks separated by periods of work, instead of taking it all in one go.
>
> To start SPL or ShPP the mother must end her maternity leave (for SPL) or her Maternity Allowance or maternity pay (for ShPP). If she doesn’t get maternity leave (but she ends her Maternity Allowance or pay early) her partner might still get SPL.
>
> If you’re adopting then you or your partner must end any adoption leave or adoption pay early instead.

From the (very sparse) link on Unpaid Parental Leave:

> Eligible employees can take unpaid parental leave to look after their child’s welfare, eg to:
>
> spend more time with their children
>
> look at new schools
>
> settle children into new childcare arrangements
>
> spend more time with family, such as visiting grandparents

As Unpaid Parental Leave is not specifically mentioned in the Tier 2 guidance, and these two types of leave do seem to be for rather distinctive purposes, I would guess that this would not be an allowed exception. All of the Tier 2 salary exceptions, including Shared Parental Leave, are focused on Maternity/Paternity/adoption/sickness. Not just general family parenting scenarios.